# Klenke's definition on exchangeable families of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

In the beginning of Ch12 (page 231) of Klenke's book "Probability theory", I find his definition on exchangeable families of random variables confusing.

> Let $I$ be an arbitrary index set and let $E$ be a Polish space. A family $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ of random variables with values in $E$ is called **exchangeable** if
>   $$\mathcal{L}\left[(X_{\pi(i)})_{i\in I}\right]=\mathcal{L}\left[(X_i)_{i\in I}\right]$$ for any finite permutation $\pi:I\rightarrow I$.

First, I cannot find any definition on $\mathcal{L}$ except the final Notation Index (page 600), which means the joint distribution of random variables, a probability measure on $E^{I}$. Just like $\mathbf{P}_X:=\mathbf{P}\circ X$? However, how to make it appropriate by defining $\mathbf{P}$ on $(X_i)^{-1}$, since I do not know whether the map $(X_i)_{i\in I}: \Omega\rightarrow E^I$ is measurable. Does this definition actually do $\mathcal{L}$ on any finite subset of $I$?

Second, I cannot figure out the equivalence between the above definition and the following statement,

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and assume $i_1,...,i_n\in I$ are pairwise distinct and $j_1,...,j_n\in I$ are pairwise distinct. Then we have $\mathcal{L}[(X_{i_1},...,X_{i_n})]=\mathcal{L}[(X_{j_1},...,X_{j_n})]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{L}(X)$ indeed denotes the distribution of $X$.

When you have a family of random variables $(X_i)_{i \in I}$, these random variables can be interpreted as a random function $I \to E$. For this you just define for every $\omega \in  \Omega$ the function $X(\omega): I \to E, X(\omega)(i) = X_i(\omega)$.

We want to call $X$ a random variable, so we need an appropriate sigma-algebra on $E^I$ [so we can actually talk about measurability]. We can trivially choose the sigma-algebra which consists only of the sets $\emptyset$ and $E^I$, however this construction is too restricted to have any meaningful application. A more "sensible" construction can be found in Kallenberg's book [I currently don't have access to it, so I can't give specific details]. Essentially this sigma-algebra is chosen in a way that makes a random function $Y: I \to E$ measurable iff $Y(i)$ is measurable for every $i \in I$.

With this choice of a sigma-algebra it can be proven [again, I don't recall all the details] that the distribution of a random function is determined by its finite-dimensional distributions This means that the distribution of $X$ is determined by the collection of distributions of $(X_{i_1}, \ldots, X_{i_n})$ for all finite subsets $\{i_1, \ldots, i_n\} \subset I$.

Comment: In the second paragraph, you want the *product* $\sigma$-field on $E^I$. In this case the map $X:\Omega\to E^I$ is measurable iff every $X_i(\omega):\Omega\to E$ is measurable. Note that we are not interested in the map $X_i(\omega):I\to E$ at all.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Yes, you are right. It is debatable whether the map $X(\omega) : I \to E$ is of interest or not, because it is essentially the outcome of the random experiment. In most applications it is of no interest, but it can be used to define the random variable $X$.

Comment: @Dominik Thanks a lot. I couldn't understand why Klenke left so many gaps to this def.